# Excel if/then formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am wondering if there is an if/then formula for the following situation. I am trying to populate a monthly calendar. I want the calendar to show the value in `A1` if the value in `B1:B100` is equal to a specific date.

```
  A                  B
1 Fees Due           15-Mar
2 Registration Open  01-Apr
```

So if the formula is entered into the March 15th cell, it would result in "Fees Due".  But on April 1st, it would show "Registration Open".

Any chance this is possible?

Comment: What does the calendar look like? Is it just a list of dates?

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is a formula that uses `INDEX` and `MATCH`. For instance, if the date you are looking up is in `D2`, you would use the following:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100,MATCH(D2,$B$1:$B$100,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use an IF statement.
Let's say your calendar dates start in cell D1 (next date is D2, and so on).
In cell E1 put the formula `=IF(D1=$B$1,$A$1,$A$2)`
You can then drag the formula down in column E

The formula references the values you put in cells A1, A2, B1 & B2, as per your original post

Comment: Why would you mark this answer as not useful?
It produces the same result, and if anything is a simpled formula to understand